# listen to an event in a package of laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

whats the correct way to listen to an event in a package in laravel ?

Inside the package service provider `class StudentServiceServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider` I have this

```
protected $listen = [
        \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login::class => [
            MyListener::class,
        ],
    ];
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add StudentServiceServiceProvider to the providers array in config/app.php

```
'providers' => [

    Pathtoclass\StudentServiceServiceProvider::class

 ]
```

Answer (score 6):

The `$listen` mapping is only used to register listeners at an app-level inside `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider`, not within a package's `ServiceProvider`.

The proper way to register an event listener from within a package's `ServiceProvier` in my opinion is to simply use the `Event` facade in it's `boot` function.

So in OP's case that would be:

```
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::listen(
            \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login::class,
            MyListener::class
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create an EventServiceProvicer and register it inside your main service provider.

```
namespace Package\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;


class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    protected $listen = [...];

    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
    }
}
```

main service provider

```
use Package\Providers\EventServiceProvider;

class PackageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/routes/routes.php');
        ...
    }

    public function register(){

        $this->app->register(EventServiceProvider::class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to specifically be extending `Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider` to have that `$listen` array be taken into account. This particular Service Provider is where that functionality that is checking for `$listen` comes from, not Service Providers in general, `Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider`.

And as mentioned, make sure your Service Provider gets registered some how.